# How to pass Parameters to BaseController and use them in the controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to share my IMapper Mapper static class across all my ASP.Net MVC controller. But don't know how to create the controller deriving from the base controller.

I tryed to pass the IMapper object as a parameter in my base controller constructor for the data injection mecanism.

But I can't figure out how to use it in my controllers deriving from the base controller.

```
// My base controller
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMapper Mapper;

        protected BaseController(IMapper mapper)
        {
            this.Mapper = mapper;
        }

// How can I declare a new controller that can use the Mapper class?
// I tried this but I get an error telling me tells me that none of the provided arguments corresponds the the formel mapper argument...  

public class MyController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IMapper Mapper;
        private readonly MyOtherParam;

        public MyController (IMapper mapper, OtherClassType myOtherParam)
        {
            this.MyOtherParam= myOtherParam;
            this.Mapper = mapper;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `Mapper` as protected field

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected readonly IMapper Mapper;

    protected BaseController(IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.Mapper = mapper;
    }
}
```

then

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
        private readonly MyOtherParam;

        public MyController (IMapper mapper, OtherClassType myOtherParam)
           :base(mapper)
        {
            this.MyOtherParam= myOtherParam;
        }
}
```

now you can use `Mapper` in derived controllers

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Comment: how do you do that? I’m new on stack overflow... I upvoted already... I don’t think I have enough credit yet that my votes are takin into account

Comment: Would this be possible somehow without having everything to go through the controllers to the base controller? I have a similar setup, and as the number of controllers increases it is a little bit of work every time I add/remove stuff from Dependency Injection.

Comment: @mathkid91 If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context